# Combine lists by object key in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to aggregate a list of objects like this:

```
[
  {"a": 1, "b": 2},
  {"a": 3, "b": 4}
]
```

To a single object with list values:

```
{
  "a": [1,3],
  "b": [2,4]
}
```

I've scoured the docs but I think I just don't know the term for what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward and efficient approach would be:

```
reduce .[] as $o ({};
  reduce ($o|keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.;
    .[$k] += [$o[$k]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) and [to_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries):

```
reduce ( .[] | to_entries[] ) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += [$value])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oNaU0OVVBQ0EvOlahRqEkPz41r6QoM7UYyNVUSCxWqFbJTq3UUSlLzClNrVXQqK61BioFicUqaNsqREMkYjUV/v@P5lJQqFZKVLJSMNRRUEoC0ka1OnAxY6iYSS1X7L/8gpLM/Lzi/7rJAA)